# Where do you store secrets or environmental details?

Tags: acumatica

I have an extension library with a URL that will differ between environments and a GUID that is used in making an API call. I don't want the GUID stored in source control, but I don't mind if it shows up in a snapshot.

Is there some mechanism in Acumatica that would help with either of these scenarios? I can't imagine that my needs are unique.

Comment: if you created your own setup page/graph/dac to store the value would this work? In each instance/company a user would be required to enter in the GUID value.

Comment: It might. Feel free to add this as an answer. I hope there are other options, but that is certainly a viable approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 options:

[1] Create a new (or reuse an existing) page/graph/dac to store your value. This would be a value per company.

[2] In a customization package, publish a file (txt, xml, etc.) that will exist in the site directory that you can then read and use site wide (all companies). The customization package can be set by you per customer as needed and distributed as a stand alone package so users do not need to edit the contents - just publish.

Answer (score 0):

As an amplification of Brendan's response, here is what someone on the Acumatica dev team said:

> They should store this in database.  They can mark those fields in DAC with `PXRSACryptStringAttribute` so that they are stored encrypted/decrypted automatically by the framework.  E.g.
>
> ```
> [PXRSACryptStringAttribute(1028)]
> [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Value")]
> public virtual String Value {get; set;}
> ```

Comment: I have not used PXRSACryptStringAttribute but that is good to know. Thanks for sharing. If you have this field on a page do you know if it displays the decrypted value to the user?

Comment: I don't know the answer but I suspect it would.